# How important is learning build system?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How important are learning build system or compiling language to develop softwares? For example i saw that ros is using catkin, or catkin build to build the ros packages or softwares. which is simular to cmake compiler language. and i also saw that most of the open source robotics related frameworks like opencv, pcl, xenomai, orocos, ace_orb all are based on cmake or make. So should i learn this compiling language in detail and as much seriously as the main programming language like c++/c, python, lua etc? If yes than why most people say that learning this is secondary and not that important for software development?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288188/how-important-is-learning-build-system?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
I believe this is rather off-topic for this forum, but in short: CMake is a DSL that allows you to configure build environments and build programs from source files. If you're going to be working with languages that need compilation, and will be using libraries and projects that already use it, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
.. then spending some time learning CMake itself (which underlies Catkin) might make sense.

You'll probably quickly come to a point where you'll want to do something 'exotic' in CMake, which will force you to learn it a bit more. Till then, reproducing "magic incantations" is probably ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin isn't hard to learn. You don't have to become an expert on it. Usually it works right the first time. I'd suggest following the tutorials, and after three or four pages of them, you'll be good to go. Much of ROS comes to you already compiled, through the framework you're familiar with (apt-get install ...) Don't worry, compute!

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-11**:
This is an ok answer, but I would emphasise the fact that `Catkin ~= CMake + some extra convenience macros`.